# Create separate list of acronyms and glossary

Tags: glossaries

I'm using glossaries at LaTeX and I want one page with the list of acronyms, then my chapters and after the chapters a separate page with a glossary. Is this possible?

This is my mainfile:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[toc,nopostdot, nonumberlist,style=long,automake]{glossaries}
\loadglsentries{Intro/Glossar}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{Roman}

  \tableofcontents

  %List of Acronyms
  \newpage
  \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Acronyms}]


  %Main Part
  \newpage
  \pagenumbering{arabic}

  \chapter{Test}
  This is a test with \acrlong{ssd} and \acrlong{ram}.
  This is a \gls{computer}.


  %Glossary      
  \printglossary[title=Glossary]

\end{document}
```

There is also a separate file "Intro/Glossar" with all glossaryentries:

```
\newacronym{ssd}{SSD}{Solid State Drive}
\newacronym{ram}{RAM}{Random Access Memory}

\newglossaryentry{computer}
{
    name=computer,
    description={is a programmable machine that receives input,
        stores and manipulates data, and provides
        output in a useful format}
}
```

I have the problem, that the list of acronyms and the glossary both show everything. Is it possible to show only the list of acronyms in the first part and the glossary-entries in the last part?

Here are some pictures from the document:

---

[image: list of acronyms]

The entry "computer" shouldn't be on this list.

---

[image: glossary]

Here there are the two acronyms "ssd" and "ram" which belong only in the "acronyms".

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the `acronym` option when loading the package:

```
\usepackage[toc,nopostdot, nonumberlist,style=long,automake,acronym]{glossaries}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! This is the solution. :)

Comment: how to write the abbreviations in bold please?